# If the site has been proposed four months ago, how can user already have the "yearling" badge?

Tags: support, badges

The site doesn't exist from more than a year, but there are [users who have already the "yearling" badge](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/52/yearling).

How is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

This is because the site was migrated from Stack Exchange 1.0. The user accounts and their histories all carried through to Stack Exchange 2.0 when the site was migrated to the newer platform.

Comment: That explains all. It's the first time that I heard of a site migrated to another one. Thank you. `:-)`